# How can I save a char into multiple variables ? C

Tags: c, arrays, variables, strtok

Ok so I need to input a string like this

`IP_1/MASK IP_2 NUM [NET_1 NET_2 NET3 ... NET_NUM]`

for example :

`192.168.25.87/24 192.168.26.1 3 192.168.0.0/16 192.0.26.0/16 192.168.26.0/24`

And then to split this string into multiple variables ( `IP_1`, `MASK` etc).
I followed on internet a guide how to split it and I did it like this:

```
int main()
{
    char* IP_1[256],IP_2[256],NET[256][256],character[256];
    int MASCA,NUM,i=1,j;
    char *p;
    gets(character);
    p=strtok(character,"/ ");
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",p);
        p=strtok(NULL,"/ ");
    }
```

So, doing this I split the array into multiple elements, but how can I save these elements into `IP_1`, `MASK IP_2`, `NUM NET_1` etc ... ?

Comment: **Never ever** use `gets`! It has been removed from the standard some years ago for good reasons.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. And what do you mean with "destroy"? All your variables have automatic storage durcation and will live until `main` ends. You cannot "destroy" variables.

Comment: I insert some dates (ips),what I write before the first / is the ip1,what i write after / and before space is his mask etc . And I want to save them into variables , for example I input 192.111.111.111/24 ,my code will take 192.111.111.111 and insert it into ip1 and 24 into mask1.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand your question

Comment: You don't want IP_1, IP_2, etc.  You surely want an array. Most likely something like `char * IP[16]`. If the maximum number of IP's is known in advance you could use a fixed size array like that. Otherwise, better practices would be to dynamically allocate that.  `char ** IP = calloc(n, sizeof(char *))`

Comment: Ok so I will try explaining it again. Input : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy Where x and y are numbers. I want to divide this input into 1 char ( ip_1) and 1 int (mask1) . So,for my input,my ip_1 will be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and my mask1 will be yy . The same I want to do with the others variables from above

Comment: Now you are having array of char *pointers* in `IP_1`. For this, you probably want arrays of char there too (which is what strings are in C, with requirement of having a 0 byte marking the end of the string):  `char IP_1[256],IP_2[256],NET[256][256],character[256];`

Comment: @johnhascal,With strncpy you can copy the first characters,but how do you delete them after from the main input ( a char ) ? That is a sollution too

Comment: ...also, I strongly suggest having 1 variable definition per line, not putting them all in 1 line, because that will avoid you some nasty mistakes, like the previous one.

Comment: @GabrielNicolae - you don't need to "delete" them from the array you read them into with `fgets()` -- you just want to skip over them.  You can either use a `char * ptr` to keep your current position in the input buffer, or you can use an `int arrayIndex` to keep your place.  Typically the `char * ptr` approach is easier because that's what `strncpy()` etc return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way.
For example, do as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char IP_1[256], IP_2[256], NET[256][256], line[256], rest[256];
    int MASK, NUM, i;
    char *p;

    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);//gets has already been abolished.
    //Since the first three elements are fixed, use sscanf
    if(3 > sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %255[^\n]%*c", IP_1, IP_2, &NUM, rest)){
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(NULL==(p = strchr(IP_1, '/'))){
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return -1;
    }
    *p = 0;// Replace '/' with '\0'
    MASK = atoi(p + 1);// convert next '/' to int

    for(p=strtok(rest, " \n"), i = 0; i < NUM && p; ++i, p=strtok(NULL, " \n")){
        strcpy(NET[i], p);//strtok and copy
    }
    //test print
    printf("IP_1:%s\n", IP_1);
    printf("MASK:%d\n", MASK);
    printf("IP_2:%s\n", IP_2);
    for(i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
        printf("NET_%d:%s\n", i + 1, NET[i]);
}
```